# WELD-001562: Producer method with Generic signature

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, weld, producer

I am using weld 4.0 and in one of my producer methods, I have this signature:

```
@Produces
  @ConfigurationType
  public <T extends IConfiguration> T getConfigurationInstance(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
                <perform some logic, create an instance of class T and return>
}
```

The objective is to have several configurations. Based on the ConfigurationType (Database/Server/Datasource blah, blah), return a Configuration instance of a specific type, that implements the IConfiguration interface so that I can treat the returned instance in a more readable format like a JDK14 record or its equivalent. In other words, I merely want to say serverConfigurationInstance.port() to read the port, where serverConfigurationInstance is *Produced* and returned by the Injector logic.

Now, the weld container when booted up tells me this:

*An exception occured while executing the Java class. WELD-001562: A producer method return type may not be a type variable or an array type whose component type is a type variable:
[ERROR]   [EnhancedAnnotatedMethodImpl] @ConfigurationType @Produces public config.ConfigurationInjector.getConfigurationInstance(InjectionPoint)
[ERROR]         at config.ConfigurationInjector.getConfigurationInstance(ConfigurationInjector.java:0)*

The Jakarta weld documentation (4.0.1) or searching for the specific error code or the message did not lead me any further. What wrong am I doing?

Comment: The answers below cover the question as asked. I wonder if you're trying to do dynamic producer stuff. If so you may find my blog article on the subject helpful: https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/dynamic-cdi-producer-methods/

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the [specs](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#producer_method), it says:

> If a producer method return type is a type variable or an array type whose component type is a type variable the container automatically detects the problem and treats it as a definition error.

This is the cause of the error you are getting.

The spec seems to allow returning a parameterized type with a type variable from a producer method, as long as the scope is `@Dependent` - which is your case. Something like:

```java
@Produces
@ConfigurationType
public <T extends IConfiguration> Supplier<T> getConfigurationInstance(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
  <perform some logic, create a supplier of an instance of class T and return>
}
```

This way however, the container "magic" (e.g. interception) will happen on the container object, not the instance of `IConfiguration` you create, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. From a polymorphic stand point, I see what you are saying. My return type is not fixed. If the document reflects this perspective, then the statement on the error message and the spec do concur.

But what confuses me is that my producer method return type is not a "type variable", rather I merely am saying I want an instance of whatever class implementing the IConfiguration interface. In a sense, this is not really a variable in that sense. IMHO, the word variable should be used for a container that has fewer restrictions.

Comment: This specific part of the link provided in the answer makes it more confusing: (Point in Line 2, Sec 3.2, Producer Methods)

The concrete type of the objects to be injected may vary at runtime, or

Comment: "The concrete type of the objects to be injected may vary at runtime": Imagine you want to produce a bean implementing an interface. You have several implementations in the classpath, but the exact one to select depends on some runtime aspect, so you cannot know at compile/assembly time. This is what point 2 is about. I am not sure I understood the first comment (sorry).